# Looping Class Property with Do While Loops

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, do-while

I have a code like below to find a category property with named "Model" and after that i will get the Model's name.

But as you can see "parent" property shows the upper level of parameter. My parameters in parameter groups and its like cascaded. And i don't know in which level they are currently i'm using below code but it's not sufficient because if i have a parameter very in lower levels i had to write this elseif conditions.

Is there any quick solution to make it easier and wise way?

```
Public Class ParameterInfoClass
    Public Shared Sub GetSubvar(ByVal ParameterGroups As IScrNamedObjectList)
        Dim ParameterGroup As IScrParameterGroup
        Dim nParameterGroup As Integer
        Dim ParameterClass As String
        nParameterGroup = ParameterGroups.count
        For i As Integer = 0 To nParameterGroup - 1
            ParameterGroup = ParameterGroups.item(i)
            If ParameterGroup.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.name
            ElseIf ParameterGroup.parent.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.parent.name
            ElseIf ParameterGroup.parent.parent.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.parent.parent.name
                '...
                'This should be continue like this because i don't know in which level i will find the category name as "Model"
                '.
            End If
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(ParameterClass, ParameterGroup.name)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

It would be great to make this section with correct solution. I thought like do-while loops can be one option but i dont know how to apply because focus is in here to look upper levels of parameter to find "Model" category after that i'm writing that Model's name.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To nParameterGroup - 1
            ParameterGroup = ParameterGroups.item(i)
            If ParameterGroup.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.name
            ElseIf ParameterGroup.parent.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.parent.name
            ElseIf ParameterGroup.parent.parent.parent.category.name = "Model" Then
                ParameterClass = ParameterGroup.parent.parent.parent.name
                '...
                'This should be continue like this because i don't know in which level i will find the category name as "Model"
                '.
            End If
```

Comment: Time to go recursive!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of time to dig into the details, but recursion is something I love so I'm giving you a hint (I would help more but that's the time I have right now).

Instead of iterating through every possible parent level, you should create a simple recursive function which will look if it finds the `"Model"`, then either return it or else look for it's parent by calling itself to look for it.

You would have to use this new function instead of your `If ElseIf ElseIf...` potentially infinite function.

I drafted something which kinda looks like what I mean:

```
Private Function GetParameterClass(rootClassName As rootClass) As String
    If ParameterGroup.category.name = "Model" Then
        Return ParameterGroup.category.name
    End If
    If ParameterGroup.parent IsNot Nothing Then
        Return GetParameterClass(ParameterGroup.parent)
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```

By calling a similar function, you will iterate recursively through every parent until it finds none, and the first time it finds `"Model"`, it'll stop the recursion and return it.

Sorry for not being more precise, as I have to get back to work myself! I'll look on your thread this evening when I can, just in case. Have fun!

EDIT:

I'm not familiar with the class you're working with, so there's a good amount of guesswork in this edit. Here's how I would try to solve your issue:

```
Public Class ParameterInfoClass
    Public Shared Sub GetSubvar(ByVal ParameterGroups As IScrNamedObjectList)
        For Each parameterGroup As IScrParameterGroup In ParameterGroups
            Dim parameterClass As String = GetParameterClassName(parameterGroup)

            If parameterName <> "" Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(parameterClass, parameterGroup.Name)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetParameterClassName(parameterGroup As IScrParameterGroup) As String
        If parameterGroup.category.name = "Model" Then
            Return parameterGroup.name
        End If
        If parameterGroup.parent IsNot Nothing Then
            Return GetParameterClass(parameterGroup.parent)
        End If

        Return ""
    End Function
End Class
```

The main idea behind `GetParameterClassName` is that it'll either find the `parameterGroup.category.name = "Model"`, or else it'll return an empty string. I replaced the way you were planning to iterate with a `For Each` loop, which should work well with most lists, but you might need to ajust that part is `IScrNamedObjectList` is not or doesn't contains a list or array or something.

Whenever a `GetParameterClassName` is found, then the `parameterClass` is not empty, so we can add these informations to the DataGridView1.

You can ask your questions in the comments if you have any, and I'll be happy to oblige. I love recursion!

Comment: thank you it seems a one of logic way but how would is it possible to get it in recursive way? When you have time i 'd like to learn how to do what you do

Comment: I edited my answer so it contains more code, which might help you better. I tried to explain a bit, but maybe that won't be the right bit, so don't hesitate to ask questions. As I'm not familiar with `IScrNamedObjectList`, there is some amount of guesswork here, so you should either see this more like formatted pseudocode, or at best as some code that you will need to adapt if you want it to do what you want. Have fun!